# How can i see what is in the cart ? Django

Tags: django, cart

I can't display the cart items. In the previous project i used django 1.11 and that code and all worked . But now i  use django 2.0 and i don't know is that i made a mistake somewhere or it is something new in django.

Cart.py in cart app

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from shop.models import Product


class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {"quantity": 0,
                                   "price": str(product.price)}
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]["quantity"] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]["quantity"] += quantity
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
        self.session.modified = True

    def remove(self, product):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def __iter__(self):
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        for product in products:
            self.cart[str(product.id)]["product"] = product

        for item in self.cart.values():
            item["price"] = Decimal(item["price"])
            item["total_price"] = item["price"] * item["quantity"]
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item["quantity"] for item in self.cart.values())

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item["price"]) * item["quantity"] for item
                    in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.session.modified = True
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from shop.models import Product
from .cart import Cart
from .forms import CartAddProductForm


@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                 quantity=cd["quantity"],
                 update_quantity=cd["update"])
    return redirect("cart:cart_detail")


def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect("cart:cart_detail")


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item["update_quantity_form"] = CartAddProductForm(
                initial={"quantity": item["quantity"],
                "update": True})
    return render(request, "cart/detail.html", {"cart": cart})
```

In template i try:

```
   {% for item in cart %}
    {% with product=item.products %}
          <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
            <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url}}
                {% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
          </a>
        {{ product.name }}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
```

or:

```
{% for item in cart %}
 <p>{{ item.product.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But i see only clear page.

In the terminal i see that item was add to the cart:

```
[08/Feb/2018 11:34:14] "POST /cart/add/3/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

But i can't display cart items in page. I use django 2.0 and python 3.6

Comment: Not sure why you think anything would have changed between 1.8 and 2.0 that would affect this. More likely, the issue is in the fact that you're accessing `item.products` in your loop, but the cart items don't seem to have a "products" key or attribute.

Comment: I thought about that. But have you any hint how should i access item in cart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my mistake, i am lost 1 string of code in cart.py.